# How to access request url pattern in express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to access the original request url pattern inside a middleware function.

Say I have this middleware:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // req.pattern ??
  next();
})
```

Since this middleware will run before all endpoints, I want to see for which endpoint the middleware is activating.

Is that possible through the Express API?

Example pattern:

```
/post/:id/views
```

Inside `req.route` is undefined though since it's a middleware, and not a route.

So what is the alternative here?

Comment: You can access the pattern on which a middleware is mounted in the [mount](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.onmount) event.

Comment: This requirement kinda breaks the chain of responsibility pattern. What if there is a next middleware that would simply abrupt the request so that it would never hit a router. Looks like [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @HeikoTheißen but that would create another instance. I would like to keep things lite.

Answer (score 0):

Only bad solution I found(since it uses unsurfaced express API):

```js
function getRoutePath(path) {
  var stack = app._router.stack;
  for (var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
    if (stack[i].route && stack[i].match(path)) {
      return stack[i].route.path;
    }
  }
}



app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const routePath = getRoutePath(req.path); // /post/:id/views
  next();
})
```