# Is it possible to convert a regex back to its original/approximate path?

Tags: javascript, regex, path-to-regexp

I have these regex expressions:

```js
/^\/users\/?(?=\/|$)/i
```

```js
/^\/?$/i
```

Which were generated using a library called [Path-to-RegExp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp)

The original paths were:

```js
/users
```

```js
/
```

So is there any way-however imperfect-to turn them back to paths?

Comment: Why? https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Check my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72405219/how-to-access-request-url-pattern-in-express

Comment: The bad solution I found, doesn't work for routers. So, i'm trying to piece it together using what express provides.

Comment: That question also look like the xy problem. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to have a global middleware that handles permissions for all routes in the application. This requires I have access to each route path. This thing I want to build makes permission management central.

Comment: Depending on the regular expression, there could be infinite valid matches. You can generate them, sure, but you won't be able to find the exact input that matched an expression from the expression alone.

Comment: @h0r53 Yeah, I thought the same. But since they're route paths, wouldn't it be possible to omit the regex characters somehow and keep what's left?

Comment: You could, but it would be unreliable at best